# jQuery className woes

Tags: jquery, classname

I'm trying to get the name of a class that matched a regex of a checked input.

If I have this:

```
 <input type="radio" class="toggle toggle-1" />
 <input type="radio" class="toggle toggle-2" checked="checked" />
 <input type="radio" class="toggle toggle-3" />
```

I want to find out that 'toggle-2' is the checked class.

```
 $('.toggle:checked').className.match(/toggle\-.+?\b/);
```

But that produced 'className is undefined' errors.

I think my problem is that I'm using className against a jQuery object. But I'm not really sure what the alternative is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call the attr method to get any underlying attributes on the element you need.

```
$('.toggle:checked').attr('class').match(/toggle\-.+?\b/);
```

Answer (score 6):

className is a standard DOM member, not a jQuery wrapper property. Either access through `$('something')[0].className` or jQuery `$('something').attr('class')`, but you can't mix them.

You appear to have multiple `radio`​s without a shared `name`? That won't work, they'll all act ast separately checkable fields. All `radio` controls that belong together need to have the same `name` (but different `value`​s) and be placed within the same form.

Comment: Nice explanation, bobince. Thanks! As for the markup, it was just for example. I omitted a bunch of attributes.

Comment: odd then it is that I've had this working since v1.4.4: var className=$("#myTBody").attr("className"); It only failed when I upgraded to v1.7.1

Comment: @kalengi: that would be due to the infamous [`attr`/`prop` split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) where jQuery tried to do the right thing (and ended up breaking everything).

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need an Id on all items jQuery is to look at?

Comment: No, jQuery can select elements based on pretty much any attribute using a wide variety of selectors.

Comment: Not at all. You can use any CSS selector (in addition to tons of other options) to locate elements in the DOM with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.toggle:checked').hasClass('toggle-2');
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, he's looking to get "toggle-2" as an answer