# Target.attr('class') is undefined in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, cross-browser

I have a Strange issue with the latest Mozilla Browser 13.0 with Ubuntu. The code works perfectly in other browsers and also previous versions of mozilla.

Here is the Code

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  var target = $(event.target);

  if (!target.attr('class').match(/^RefineClick/) && target.parents('.RefineClick').length == 0) {
   jQuery('.RefineClick').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

And iam getting the following Error : 
Target.attr('class').... is undefined

Here is the Screenshot for that: http://i47.tinypic.com/dqoits.png

Comment: Why are you selecting this way instead of using jQuery's selectors?

Comment: How about using `hasClass` method instead of that wonderful code with the regular expression?

Comment: Try `var target = $(event.target || e.srcElement);`. @VisioN i think `hasClass` isn't accurate when there are multiple classes involved, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @jSang You are wrong. It should work fine.

Comment: Except `.hasClass` won't match RefineClick1 for example, where his match method will.

Comment: Can you please rewrite the code as you told. because i'am new to jquery. I need was when a popup comes and user clicks any where in the document, the popup should fadeout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925276/jquery-classname-woes

Comment: http://thicksliced.blogspot.com/2006/12/elementgetattributeclass.html

Answer (score 0):

Well... working for me?

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/b9MCj/

Comment: can u workout with my code ?  I need was when a popup comes and user clicks any where in the document, the popup should fadeout.

Comment: kind of that... [http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/b9MCj/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/b9MCj/1/)

Comment: cant see original code to handle parents class :) not really clear what and when you'd like to hide stuff

Answer (score 0):

If there is no class attached to the clicked element `target.attr('class')` returns `undefined` (since v1.6); in FF that's expressed as the error you see when you attempt to call `.match`. (In chrome it would be "can't call method match of undefined")

Add a check for an absent class; `if (typeof target.attr('class') === "undefined") return;`

Comment: if (target.attr('class')) wont pass as well... and looks better :)

Answer (score 0):

You are binding that function to a 'click' event on the entire document. Therefore *any* click would trigger the handler, including those on elements without a class attribute set. While this would work fine if you tested it only on elements with a defined 'class' attribute (in any browser) it would throw the error (in *any* browser) because you try and call the method `.match()` on an `undefined` value.

*"As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set."* [API ref.](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Since you are using jQuery, who not use it's full capabilities? It has a built in [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);

    if (!target.hasClass('RefineClick') && target.parents('.RefineClick').length == 0) {
        $('.RefineClick').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Note that the input to that method is the class-name rather than a class selector.