# Changing Class Function is Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checked my javascript and it shows no error, but it is not doing anything at all.

Here is the html code:

```
<body>
    <!--The div who's function isn't working-->
    <div id="sliderButtonB" onclick='pageSliderBack()'>Go Back</div>    
    <!--End of not-functioning div-->
    <!--The Slider That is supposed to change **backwards** -->
    <div id='slidecarousel' class='p1' onclick='pageSlider(this)'>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the not-functioning javascript:

```
function pageSliderBack(){
    var pDiv = $('#slidecarousel')
    if ( pDiv.attr("class").match(/(?:^|\s)p1(?!\S)/) ){
         pDiv.className = "p5";
    } else if ( pDiv.attr("class").match(/(?:^|\s)p2(?!\S)/) ){
        pDiv.className = "p1";
    } else if ( pDiv.attr("class").match(/(?:^|\s)p3(?!\S)/) ){
        pDiv.className = "p2";
    } else if ( pDiv.attr("class").match(/(?:^|\s)p4(?!\S)/) ){
        pDiv.className = "p3";
    } else if ( pDiv.attr("class").match(/(?:^|\s)p5(?!\S)/) ){
        pDiv.className = "p4";
    } else {
        pDiv.className = "SlideErr";
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of the javascript on the page; This function works, but the other doesn't:

```
function pageSlider(elem){
    if ( elem.className.match(/(?:^|\s)p1(?!\S)/) ){
         elem.className = "p2";
    } else if ( elem.className.match(/(?:^|\s)p2(?!\S)/) ){
        elem.className = "p3";
    } else if ( elem.className.match(/(?:^|\s)p3(?!\S)/) ){
        elem.className = "p4";
    } else if ( elem.className.match(/(?:^|\s)p4(?!\S)/) ){
        elem.className = "p5";
    } else if ( elem.className.match(/(?:^|\s)p5(?!\S)/) ){
        elem.className = "p1";
    } else {
        elem.className = "SlideErr";
    }
}
```

Comment: Change function pageSliderBack(elem) to function pageSliderBack()

Comment: change  onclick='pageSliderBack()' with  onclick='pageSliderBack(this)'

Comment: Thanks for the suggested edit!

Comment: he never uses the parameter in the function, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves your problem and cleans your code:

```
function pageSliderBack(){     
    var pDiv = $('#slidecarousel');
    if ( pDiv.hasClass("p1") ) pDiv.removeClass("p1").addClass("p5");
    else if ( pDiv.hasClass("p2") ) pDiv.removeClass("p2").addClass("p1");
    else if ( pDiv.hasClass("p3") ) pDiv.removeClass("p3").addClass("p2");
    else if ( pDiv.hasClass("p4") ) pDiv.removeClass("p4").addClass("p3");
    else if ( pDiv.hasClass("p5") ) pDiv.removeClass("p5").addClass("p4");
    else pDiv.addClass("SlideErr");    
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 2):

Just as in your last quertion, you're trying to access a DOM property on a jQuery element. It should be:

```
pDiv[0].className = "p5";
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/un5tR/2/)

Comment: can I do that when I declared the variable?(e.g.var pdiv = $('#slidecarousel')[0])

Comment: Yes, then you'll have to use `pdiv.className.match` instead of `pdiv.attr('class').match`.

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of confusion if you stick to raw Javascript or jQuery throughout, instead of switching back and forth.

Comment: Also, try to get rid of all that repeated code. Just get the number at the end of the class, add or subtract 1 to it, and then assign that as the new class.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `pageSliderBack` your are using jquery element i.e `$('#slidercarousel')` but setting `className` using normal javascript

Check [jQuery className woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925276/jquery-classname-woes)

instead use

```
pDiv.attr("class", 'p5'); or use pDiv.addClass('p5')
```